# How to replace foreground service in android app widget?

Tags: java, android

There is a appwidget in my android app.

features of appwidget

- If user press button of appwidget, it request backend api.
- Update view with api result.

I originally wrote app widget with foreground service.
Because I thought that work like it cannot be handled without service.

But, for now, Foreground service in app widget is restricted in Android 12 or higher.

So I should modify it with other way.

Which method can I choose in this case?

Comment: Use `WorkManager` and schedule work to make the backend call and update the app widget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.